# Service Bus PeekLock issue with Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have multiple message in my Service Bus Topic and I would like to process this message one by one and on a Service Bus Trigger, it should get all the messages which has not been processed. and since I am doing testing and debugging, I would not like the messages to be completed i.e. if it is not completed it stays in the topic for any other services to consume.

I have started with Azure Function App with Service Bus Topic Trigger and have moved up til here where I get all the message in my log but once it is done, I don't get any other messages because all have been consumed and they move to the "Dead-letter message count", so its become very difficult for me to do any debugging and testing.

I would like to know how can I handle this with Azure Function Service Bus trigger where I run the Function see the body of my message in console, exit it and then do the necessary transformation and then repeat the process. Without service bus trigger, I can do it with PeekLock thing and dont allow any message to be completed, but how do i do it with Function as it seems to take the messages at once for triggering.

```
 namespace ServiceBusCopyFunction
{
    public static class GetMetadataFromSB
    {
        static ISubscriptionClient subscriptionClient;
        [FunctionName("GetMetadataFromSB")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("TopicNameSB", "SubscriptionNameSB", Connection = "AzureServiceBusString")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's no peek in Azure Function Binding. For developing purpose, I'm using Service Bus Explorer: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

It's easy to send messages (again) and move them from Dead-Letter to the topic

Comment: but i don't have that flexibility as messages I am getting is from client and I have to work on those messages and cant insert by my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deactivate the *autoComplete* functionality in the *host.json* file. Here's the reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings

Example:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the messages won't get completed after processing them.

Comment: I dont see that option in host.json, should I add my own in there?? now I have this>

{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Yes please just add the _extensions_ section and the content below to the json file. It should look somewhat like:
`{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I m not sure what happens, but it does not seem to working any more. I am loosing the messages in the subscription after few minutes to dead messages once I run the code and got few exceptions. is that something to do with exceptions??