# Service Bus PeekLock issue with Azure Function on Exceptions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373740/service-bus-peeklock-issue-with-azure-function) is question but I am posting it here again as It seems to work but after I catch an exception , my messages moves to dead-letter message count. Is there any timeout property or any thing I can do to just stop letting the messages get completed.

Comment: Usually messages only get deadlettered if they run into exceptions and exceed the retry count. Do you throw the exception after catching it?

Comment: yes I am doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, messages get requeued when an uncaught exception occurs. This happens until the *maxDeliveryCount* property is reached (by default 10 times). If you don't want the messages to get deadlettered and requeued, you need to catch the exception and *not* throw it.